# WooCommerce deletes all but 1 product file for Variable Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Variable product is a downloadable, digital product and includes 3 separate files. I can add all 3 files, but after pressing "Save Changes" or "Update" only 1 product file remains. This is happening for all of my variable products with multiple files.

I pulled a backup to a local environment, changed the theme to Twenty Nineteen, deactivated all plugins except WooCommerce and the issue remains. 
I've tried pulling the files directly from the Media Folder and also using a URL.

Simple products with multiple product files appear to be saving correctly.

Environment:
WooCommerce v. 4.0.0
WordPress 5.3.2
Server: Apache
PHP Version: 7.3.11
MySQL Version: 5.6.34-log

Thanks for your help.